# How to define more than one server environment in Fabric(Python)?

Tags: python, fabric

I need to use Fabric to do some operations in a website that use one machine for the filesystem and other machine to the database server. I need to handle two hosts. How can I do that?

I have some code but I cannot get the environment definition to work.

The idea is to connect to the remote Filesystem server and get the files and then connect to the remote Database server and get the database schema.

The code that I have for now is something like this:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

'''
Here I define where is my "aid"s file structure
'''
local_root = '/home/andre/test' # This is the root folder for the audits 
code_location = '/remote_code' # This is the root folder dor the customer code inside each audit


#
# ENVIRONMENTS CONFIGURATIONS
#
'''
Here I configure where is the remote file server
'''
def file_server():
    env.user = 'andre'
    env.hosts = ['localhost']

'''
Here I configure where is the database server
'''
def database_server():
    env.user = 'andre'
    env.hosts = ['192.168.5.1']  


#
# START SCRIPT
#
def get_install(remote_location, aid):
    ### I will get the files
    '''
    Here I need to load the file_server() definitions
    '''    
    working_folder = local_root + '/%s' % aid # I will define the working folder 
    local('mkdir ' + working_folder) # I will create the working folder for this audit
    local('mkdir ' + working_folder + code_location) # I will create the folder to receive the code
    get(remote_location, working_folder + code_location) # I will download the code to my machine
    ### I will get the database
    '''
    Here I need to load the database_server() definitions
    ''' 
    local('dir') # Just to test
```

How can I inside get_install() define the environments file_server() and database_server() ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe you can split up your get_install function into two functions each for every server.

Then limit those functions to the correct servers with fabric.decorators.hosts(*host_list) decorator:

For example, the following will ensure that, barring an override on the command line, my_func will be run on host1, host2 and host3, and with specific users on host1 and host3:

```
@hosts('user1@host1', 'host2', 'user2@host3')
def my_func():
    pass
```

(For more info see http://readthedocs.org/docs/fabric/en/1.1.0/api/core/decorators.html#fabric.decorators.hosts)

And you can than call those 2 functions in one go by defining your get_install method as:

```
def get_install():
    func1()
    func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with `fab database_server get_install`. Basically, fab [environment] [command] should do what you want.

Comment: there is a way of doing this for file_server() and for database_server() running "fab get_install"? I'm doing like you said, but I need to do it at once. It is possible?

Comment: You mean by just typing one command? I don't think so. The whole point is to have actions independent of environments and then be able to swap the environment out. But I don't know Fabric that well, so maybe there is.